# Get a 403 when using dual authorization (Bearer & Basic) in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have a case where I want both authentication with Bearer tokens and Basic authentication, but I am getting a 403 Forbidden every time Basic is used([Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]).

.
This is my startup.cs:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ...
        };
    })
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("BasicAuthentication",
        authBuilder =>
        {
            authBuilder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("BasicAuthentication");
            authBuilder.RequireClaim("NameIdentifier");

        });
});
```

And I have added a handler for Basic:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");

        ...

        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
}
```

The handler is returning Success for the right cases, but is still returning a 403.

Comment: Prefer not to edit your question with the correct answer like you did, keep the question the same and add an answer Or Mention this Update with BOLD text in your answer Besides keep the old Code as it too.

Comment: Also, Your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591240/1908296 is not related to Solving the problem you faced, it is Just completing your Custom Authentication implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing the setup: I created an extension method for adding my policy and authenticationhandler:

```
    public static class BasicAuthExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddBasicAuthorization(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection
        .AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddBasicPolicy();
        })
        .AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

        return serviceCollection;
    }

    public static AuthorizationOptions AddBasicPolicy(this AuthorizationOptions options)
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("BasicAuthentication")
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

        options.AddPolicy("BasicPolicy", policy);
        return options;
    }
}
```

Then I added it in startup.cs:

```
            services
            .AddBasicAuthorization()
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = "Audience",
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you missed the `authenticationType` parameter when constructing the identity :

```
    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,Scheme.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think you are right, but there seems to be more than one issue. I added the scheme name, but I still get a 403.

Comment: @Arnstein Actually, I've tested my code above, it works as expected. If you have logined in before, please logout firstly. If you still get a 403, please feel free to update me.