# AspNetCore custom authentication scheme authenticates then fails authorization

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm migrating a legacy custom header thingy to IdentityServer client credentials flow.

So that both systems can run simultaneously I want to add a second authentication scheme to my API that supports the legacy systems during a changeover period.

I've created

```
public class MyProductAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MyProductAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
```

and hooked it up in `Startup.cs` with

```
.AddScheme<MyProductAuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyProductAuthenticationHandler>(MyProductAuthenticationSchemeOptions.AuthenticationScheme, _ => { });
```

and I can set a breakpoint in its `HandleAuthenticateAsync` and check that it's succeeding and making an `AuthenticationTicket`.

However, *authorization* subsequently fails (it still works for the JWT token authorization).
I see these messages in the logging output.

```
MyProduct.Api.Services.Auth.MyProductAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: MyProductwas successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
MyProduct.Api.Services.Auth.MyProductAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: MyProduct was forbidden.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
MyProduct.Middleware.LoggingMiddleware: Warning: 403 @ GET /api/global/manage/tenants/TenantNameAvailable
```

The problem seems to be that

> `AuthenticationScheme: MyProduct was forbidden`

but why is it forbidden after it authorized?

My policy is

```
                options.AddPolicy(MyProductAuthorizationPolicy.GlobalTenantManagement, policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(MyProductAuthenticationSchemeOptions.AuthenticationScheme); // Obsolete. Remove after switching to client credentials flow.
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("client_id", "client");
                    policy.RequireClaim("my_product_management", "global");
                });
```

If I change my policy to

```
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(TruthLiteAuthenticationSchemeOptions.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); // If absent then there are no claims below.
                    policy.RequireAssertion((context) => {
                        int c = context.User.Claims.Count();
                        return true;
                    });
```

then then `HandleAuthenticateAsync` runs and I get the cliams, but

> `AuthenticationScheme: MyProduct was forbidden.`

happens again and 403 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Having found
[Get a 403 when using dual authorization (Bearer & Basic) in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575044/get-a-403-when-using-dual-authorization-bearer-basic-in-net-core)

I guessed that the answer was to pass the scheme name as a parameter to the constructor of `ClaimsIdentity` in my `HandleAuthenticateAsync`, i.e.,

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Scheme.Name);
```

instead of

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
```